# Telerik Style Builder Not working

Tags: asp.net, telerik, skin

I'm trying to build a custom skin using [Telerik skin builder](http://stylebuilder.telerik.com). upon modifying the default skin it doesn't get reflected.

Please note: i tried with FireFox, IE and Chrome with some results.

Comment: explain what exactly is not working with you, or contact Telerik for help with their tools. Once you get the skin from the visual style builder, you must first incorporatre it in your projet like any other custom skin.

Answer (score -1):

This message thread might help:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-skin-not-working

Comment: Thanks Rafet. csutom skins is working fine with me, but i trying to create a skin using Telerik style build and its no working properly with me.